# Grab Comments related to Post

Tags: angularjs, firebase

I have posts stored like this: posts {id, text},{id,text} and so on.

I have comments stored separately injecting the id of the post a value of the comment: comments {id, text, postId}, {id, text, postId}, etc...

How can I get the data? return $firebase(ref.child('comments').child('???').child('Postid').$asObject();

I want to be able to insert the post id into the function and return all the comments. Any tips?

I'm using angularjs and firebase as backened obviously. Everything else has been working fine. I am just trying to understand the logic of firebase, and how to implement a solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found was to store the data in comments branch under the post id, rather than using the post id as a field of data to search.

Comment: More on this in [structuring data](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/structuring-data.html) and [reading data](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/retrieving-data.html).